# ImageMagick: placing a frame along the edges of an image

Tags: imagemagick

What is the most efficient, idiomatic way with ImageMagick to turn this:

[image]

Into this:

[image]

Please note: canvas size remains unchanged, a frame of arbitrary color and width is applied "on top" of the original image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I would just shave 30 pixels off then add 30 pixels of border back on:

```
convert rose.jpg -shave 30 -bordercolor cyan -border 30 result.png
```

[image]

I'll let you do the colour-matching ;-)